# scikit learn - converting features stored as strings into numbers

Tags: csv, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm currently dipping my toes into machine learning using the scikit-learn python library and am trying to use some .CSV data in the format

```
Date        Name                    Average_Price_SA
1995-01-01  Barking And Dagenham    70885.331285935
1995-01-01  Barnet                  99567.4268042005
1995-01-01  Barnsley                49608.33494746
....
....
....
2005-01-01  Barking And Dagenham    13294.12321312
```

I have read them in using panda using the line

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

From what I have learned so far, I think I'm supposed to convert those 'Name' category strings into floats so that they can be accepted into a model.

I'm not sure how to go about this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. Without more information on the task, this is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use scikit's `LabelBinarizer` to convert the strings to one hot vectors. These have N zeros (where N is the number of unique strings) with a one at a single component.

```py
from __future__ import print_function
from sklearn import preprocessing

names = ["Barking And Dagenham", "Barnet", "Barnsley"]
lb = preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()
vectors = lb.fit_transform(names)
for name, vector in zip(names, vectors):
    print("%s => %s" % (name, str(vector)))
```

Output:

```
Barking And Dagenham => [1 0 0]
Barnet => [0 1 0]
Barnsley => [0 0 1]
```